# printing in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7

```
Class = ["Gabriel","Isabella","Veronica","Hunter","John"]
num = [1,2,3,4,5]


for i in num :
    for z in Class :
        print "%d.  %s"%(i,z)
```

The above is printing this:

> ```
> 1.  Gabriel
> 1.  Isabella
> 1.  Veronica
> 1.  Hunter
> 1.  John
> 2.  Gabriel
> 2.  Isabella
> 2.  Veronica
> 2.  Hunter
> 2.  John
> 3.  Gabriel
> 3.  Isabella
> 3.  Veronica
> 3.  Hunter
> 3.  John
> 4.  Gabriel
> 4.  Isabella
> 4.  Veronica
> 4.  Hunter
> 4.  John
> 5.  Gabriel
> 5.  Isabella
> 5.  Veronica
> 5.  Hunter
> 5.  John
> ```
>
> I would like to have it only once of each like this:
>
> 1. Gabriel
> 2. Isabella
> 3. Veronica
> 4. Hunter
> 5. John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i,z in zip(num, Class):
    print "%d.  %s"%(i,z)
```